# How to create 2D array and the size is given as a variable in objective-c

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to objective-c. I have trouble in the 2D array. Since I have some javascript knowledge. I'll try to explain it with javascript.

```
var row = 10;
var col = 10;
var array[row][col];

for (var i = 0; i < row; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < col; j++){
        //do something in here
    }
}

row = 20;
col = 20;

for (var i = 0; i < row; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < col; j++){
        //do something in here
    }
}
```

How to code this in objective-c?

Comment: In ECMAScript, `var array[row][col]` is a syntax error.

Comment: In objective c you don't specify the size of the array when you declare the variable. You will simply allocate an NSMutableArray and add NSMutableArrays to it.

Comment: I think i mixed up with java...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
NSInteger row = 10;
NSInteger col = 10;

// Array with variable size. For fixed size, use [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:row]
NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < row; i++) {

    // You must add values before you can access them. You cannot access a value at an index which is greater than the size of the array

    NSMutableArray* colArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    [array addObject:colArray];

    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < col; j++) {


        [colArray addObject:someObject];

        // You can access the array like such:
        id object = array[i][j];

        // You can change an existing value in the array using the same notation:
        array[i][j] = someObject;

        // You cannot set an array value to nil or null. Instead use NSNull which is an object you can use to represent a null value:
        array[i][j] = [NSNull null];
    }
}


// You can also initialise an array with the following notation if you know the values in advance:

NSArray* anotherArray = @[objectOne, objectTwo, objectThree];

// Similarly, you can create a 2-dimensional array as follows:

NSArray* twoDimensionalArray = @[
                                 @[rowOneColumnOne, rowOneColumnTwo, rowOneColumnThree],
                                 @[rowTwoColumnOne, rowTwoColumnTwo, rowTwoColumnThree]
                                 ];
```